# Customize Stencil Order Confirmation page

Tags: e-commerce, bigcommerce

I have been searching this for hours and I am not getting anything useful.

In BigCommerce Stencil theme, is it possible to customize/create custom template for the `order-confirmation.html` page? specifically the content of `{{checkout.order_confirmation_content}}`

If there is not, is there a workaround or something? I mean there must be a way to change the **HTML** of that page.

#### NOTE:

I want to change the **HTML** not just the **CSS**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the only checkout flow that supports editing the content of the confirmation page is Custom One-Page Checkout (for Developers). Developer Checkout gives you full access to the html for the checkout and confirmation page. You can access this setting under Advanced Settings>Checkout in your control panel.

Once enabled, navigate to Storefront>Checkout Template Files (you may need to refresh to see this option appear). The order confirmation page is order.html.

Answer (score 0):

The optimized one-page checkout flow /checkout/order-confirmation supports customization of theme\templates\pages\order-confirmation.html by adding language strings to your localization.

get a copy of `opt-checkout-en.json` from https://developer.bigcommerce.com/stencil-docs/localization/multi-language-checkout

```
{
    "optimized_checkout": {
        "order_confirmation": {
            "order_number_text": "Your order number is <strong>{orderNumber}</strong>",
            "order_pending_review_text": "Your order was sent to us but is currently awaiting payment. Once we receive the payment for your order, it will be completed. If you've already provided payment details then we will process your order manually and send you an email when it's completed.",
            "order_with_downloadable_digital_items_text": "You can download your digital purchases by clicking the links on this page, or by logging into your account at any time. There is also a download link in your confirmation email, which should be arriving shortly.",
            "order_with_support_number_text": "An email will be sent containing information about your purchase. If you have any questions about your purchase, email us at <a ng-href=\"mailto:{supportEmail}?Subject=Order {orderNumber}\" target=\"_top\">{supportEmail}</a> or call us at <a href=\"tel://{supportPhoneNumber}\">{supportPhoneNumber}</a>.",
            "order_without_downloadable_digital_items_text": "Once we receive your payment, we’ll send a confirmation email with a link to download your digital purchases.",
            "order_without_support_number_text": "An email will be sent containing information about your purchase. If you have any questions about your purchase, email us at <a ng-href=\"mailto:{supportEmail}?Subject=Order {orderNumber}\" target=\"_top\">{supportEmail}</a>.",
            "thank_you_customer_heading": "Thank you {name}!",
            "thank_you_heading": "Thank you!",
            "order_status_update_facebook_messenger_heading": "Get instant updates of your order to Messenger"
        }
    }
}
```

It's unclear to me where supportEmail comes from.